# Installing Microsoft CRM 3.0 Error Groups Do not exist

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I am doing a fresh install of CRM 3.0.

During the check list of requirements before the set up will continue I am getting the following error:

> One more more Microsoft CRM groups do not exist

I figured this installation would set up the groups automatically - guess I was wrong.  So after reading the doc's CRM requires 4 groups (PriUserGroup, SQLAccessGroup, UserGroup, ReportingGroup).

So I opened the Active Directory and Added the four groups manually to the domain.local and tried the install again and got the same message.

Any ideas why?  I guess I need to put the group in a specify dir under my domain.local (ie: in "MyBusiness" or "MyBusiness/SecurityGroups" etc) but I don't know where or if this is correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with http://www.c7solutions.com/blog/2008/04/crm-30-disaster-recovery.aspx - but the BuildVersion didn't have to be changed.

Comment: Please flag this as answer